# Newsletter plugin custom button text on impresspage

Tags: php, html, impresspages

I install Newsletter plugin of impresspage,

in widget files i couldn't found way to change text of button "SubScribe"
and edit plugin html view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's "ImpressPages" (camelCase and plural).

HTML output of widgets is controlled with skins (https://www.impresspages.org/docs/widgets). By default is in `\Plugin\Newsletter\Widget\Newsletter\skin\default.php`. You can change it directly or override in your theme.

If done correctly, all strings are translatable. Install a plugin (http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/AsdTranslate) for easy translations, look for required string and translate/change it.

Another option is to change the source. Check where that string comes from. Here's where form comes from:

```
\Plugin\Newsletter\Model::createForm();
```

Open `Model.php`, search for `createForm()` method and look for submit field. And do what you want with it.